# Broken textures(?) after resuming from sleep

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, suspend

After resuming I have a graphics issue with textures (not sure, see screenshots).

Windows frame:

[image: about window]

Viber app:

[image: viber app]

Also some other apps are affected.

Some video info:

```
$ lspci | grep 'VGA\|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M] (rev a1)

$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 970M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 375.39
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 375.39
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 375.39
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Unity reload (Alt+F2 → `unity`) helps, but it crashes the most of open apps.

Any suggestions?

**UPD:** seems like it is bug of NVidia card/driver (reproduced with `nvidia-367`, `nvidia-370`, `nvidia-375`, `nvidia-378`).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue - "fixed" by rolling back to NVIDIA-367:

Steps:

- remove/disable driver PPA Purge all previous drivers check 367 is
  newest available install 367 & restart
- goto software/sources, find the NVIDIA drivers and disable, exit and this -should force package update, then open up a terminal:
- sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
- sudo ubuntu-drivers devices    #check that 367 is available
- sudo apt-get install nvidia-367
- restart the computer

Comment: Didn't help. I updated the question with `nvidia-367`.  Also, 367 has this issue http://askubuntu.com/q/867815/123650 .